# JFrame closing on dialog

Tags: java, swing

```
public static int clickOnExit() {
    int dialogButton=JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, sharedConstants.exitMessage,"Confirm",dialogButton);
    if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){return JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;}
    else{return JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE;}

}
```

for confirm(YES) it works, but i am not sure if cancel option is  solved properly. i just want to cancel JOptionPane and keep frame opened.

Comment: See [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for more information on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do three things:

1. Set your main application frame to do nothing on close.

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

2. Register a `WindowListener` that listens to the `windowClosing` event.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        maybeExit(); // Will not return if user clicks yes.
        super.windowClosing(e);
    }
});
```

3. Write code to conditionally call `System.exit` if the user confirms they wish to exit the application.

```
private void maybeExit() {
    int yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `System.exit`. It's better to dispose that frame and when the last frame is disposed, the JVM will shutdown automatically.

Comment: @Jaroslaw: Isn't that only the case if the frame's default close operation is set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE?

Comment: As far as I remember, the default operation is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`. It all depends on what OP needs. I would say that disposing is safer, because one day you add another frame that you want to stay open after you close the first frame, and it turns out that you need to change existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions were useful. I solved it in this way:

```
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            if (HandlingDialogBox.clickOnExit(frame) == 0) {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            } else {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

AND

```
 public static int clickOnExit(final JFrame frame) {
     return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,sharedConstants.exitMessage,"Confirm",
     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}
```

Sorry for bit messy parenthesis use, will clean that up later ...